# The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Por alguna razón mis proyectos de **visual studio** no funcionan, lo único que logro es conseguir este mensaje:

> **The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo que indica si existe en mi computadora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas ya reinstale visual studio.

Si alguien supiera como solucionarlo se lo agradecería mucho:

Comment: Hola. Puedes mostrarnos el contenido de los archivos de proyecto que no te cargan?

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra, practicamente ningun proyecto se carga, ademas de que tampoco los puedo crear.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo lleves esos proyectos a una ruta mas corta. Por ejemplo "C:\src\xxx". No he contado los caracteres de las rutas que se ven en tus capturas de pantalla pero el limite para Visual Studio son unos 250 caracteres.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra, pero funcionaban correctamente hasta ayer por la noche, hoy al despertar ya no funcionaban...

Comment: Hola, has instalado algun plugin tipo Resharper o algo?

Comment: No, nada de eso

Comment: Has probado a reinstalar el Framework?

Comment: Hola. Prueba a deshabilitar esta opción. Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Allow parallel project initialization. Lo pongo en ingles ya que así tengo configurado mi VS. Tambien te recomiendo actualizar tu VS al último Update disponible.

Comment: Ese archivo es un xml. Prueba a validarlo por si tienes algun error en el. Pégalo tambien en la pregunta por si podemos ver algun error en el

Comment: @Pikoh, ese achivo solo lo veia para saber si contenia algo de informacion para el error, he provado reinstalando el todos los framework y hasta actualize wimdows y todo lo de visual... Al final la **Solucion** en mi caso fue **Formatear mi Computadora**, ya que no tenia tiempo para poder probar mas opciones.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra, mil gracias por la ayuda, pero al final nada funciono... como ya escribi la solucion para mi caso fue **Formatear la computadora** y reinstalar todo.